# Could not find any INDEX file for image package

Tags: image, octave

On trying to invoke `imshowpair` or `montage` I get

```
error: could not find any INDEX file in directory E:\Octave\share\octave\packages\image-2.8.0, 
try pkg rebuild all to generate missing INDEX files
error: called from
describe>parse_pkg_idx at line 94 column 5
describe at line 59 column 39
pkg at line 566 column 41
__unimplemented__>check_package at line 519 column 13
__unimplemented__ at line 321 column 11
```

Can't quite seem to figure out what is causing this. Other image functions like imread and imshow work fine. pkg rebuild all does not fix anything.

This is Octave 4.4.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: imread and imshow are core octave, not image pkg. imshowpair does not seem to be implemented yet. are you sure you installed the image package correctly? is it installed in the location referenced in the error? what happens if you try to reinstall it? where does pkg list say it's installed?

Answer (score 0):

By the error, it seems that the package folder is there, but not the contents, so you may need to reinstall the image package:

```
pkg install -forge image
```

(Sometimes it takes a while as it generates document cache)

After it is installed, don't forget to load the package:

```
pkg load image
```

There is a new version 2.8.1 out from 19-Nov-2018, but it does not currently contain a version of imshowpair.